# How can we change elasticsearch cluster name character length

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Elasticsearch configuration would generate resources with invalid names: name exceeds maximum allowed length of 36"

Seems it is a default length of ES cluster name. How can we change it to 40 in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

It is restricted 36 in k8's env.
Reference page: https://github.com/elastic/cloud-on-k8s/blob/master/pkg/controller/common/name/name.go#L21